# Vue-router with webpack, can't access $route

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-router

```
<template>
<div>
    {{$route.params}}
    <button v-on:click="test">dasda</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    methods: {
        test: () => {
        var test = this.$route;
           console.dir(test);
        }
    },
    created: () => {
    console.log(this.$route);
   }
}

</script>
```

I can access the `$route` in the binding, the correct parameter will be shown but if I try to access the `$route` object, it's undefined. 
I'm using Webpack and with the vuejs devtools the `$route` object is found, but I have no idea how to access it. If I directly print the `$route` object, it will be undefined too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use arrow functions on your components. They have to be bound to the component's context.

Instead, use proper methods:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        test () {
            var test = this.$route;

            console.dir(test);
        },
    },
    created () {
        console.log(this.$route);
    },
};
```